# Русский язык за лето

Tags: обучение

Мне нужно выучить Русский язык, 8 классов за одно лето, без репетитора. Может есть какие нибудь книжки или сайт. Подскажите.

Answer (score 2):

Сколько угодно.  Ваши учебники за все классы, в школьной библиотеке или в магазине возьмите справочник Розенталя. Ещё в помощь множество сайтов, например, эти: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=223  -справочник Лопатина
http://antic-r.narod.ru/lingua.htm - интересное о русском языке (для детей)
Главное - очень захотеть и если начал - не останавливаться,каждый день понемногу, по теме-две, по учебнику подряд, с выполнением упражнений и тестов, в Интернете есть тесты по всем классам, есть и тесты -онлайн.Мы очень приветствуем такое желание. Успехов!

Comment: Моё желание возникло  из-за того что все 8 классов я занимался ни чем

Comment: Бывает, главное - вовремя это осознать и начать заниматься полезным делом - ликвидировать все пробелы. Первый: ничем - отрицательное местоимение пишется слитно, если внутри нет предлога, раздельно - если есть предлог: ни о чём, ни с чем, ни к чему.

Comment: Вы молодец, что все-таки решили подтянуть грамотность. Кстати, "заниматься НИЧЕМ" пишется слитно.  
Только думаю, по школьным учебникам за одно лето все не подтянуть. Тут надо поискать ускоренные, может быть, какие-то альтернативные методики. А еще совет из личной практики: пишите побольше и не стесняйтесь спрашивать в сложных случаях. Мы всегда рады помочь тому, кто искренне хочет писать грамотно!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь